# Download millions of image using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am working on a node application which will download millions of map tiles(images) from map server, and the url of the tile will be generated dynamically by the zoom level and coordinate of x and y, here are the codes:

```
var tpl_url="http://tile.server.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
var z= 19 ,x_range=[0,10000],y_range=[0,10000],down_dir="download";
function generateUrl(z,x,y){
    var obj={x:x,y:y,z:z};
    return tpl_url.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/g,function(a,key){
        return obj[key];
    });
}
function generateFilePath(z,x,y){
    return path.join(down_dir,z.toString(),x.toString(),y+".png");
}
function download(url,path,callback){
    request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path)).on('error',function(e){
        callback && callback(e,url);
    }).on('close',function(){
        callback && callback(null,url);
    });
}
var num = 0;
function onTileLoaded(err,url){
    console.log(url+"\t " + (!err?"complete ":"error") + (++num));
}

for(var i=x_range[0];i<=x_range[1];i++){
    for(var k=y_range[0];k<=y_range[1];k++){
        var x = i,y = k;
        var  url = generateUrl(z,x,y);
        var filePath = generateFilePath(z,x,y);
        fs.exists(path.dirname(filePath),function(exists){
            if(!exists){
                mkdirp(path.dirname(filePath),function(){
                    download(url,filePath,onTileLoaded);
                });
            }else{
                download(url,filePath,onTileLoaded);
            }
        });
        console.log("iterator:" + i + "," + k);
    }
}
```

Now I got three problems:

**1 Value of variables are overridden**

Obvious, this will not work since the `fs.exists` are asynchronous operation, when the operation done, the variables like `url` `filePath` will be overridden by the next loop, generally I will close these variables by closure like this:

```
for(var i...){
    for(var k...){
            var x = i,y = k;
            var  _url = generateUrl(z,x,y);
            var _filePath = generateFilePath(z,x,y);
            (function(url,filePath){
                fs.exists(path.dirname(filePath),function(exists){
                    if(!exists){
                        mkdirp(path.dirname(filePath),function(){
                            download(url,filePath,onTileLoaded);
                        });
                    }else{
                        download(url,filePath,onTileLoaded);
                    }
                });
            })(_url,_filePath);

        console.log("iterator:" + i + "," + k);
    }
}
```

It worked, but it seems that means once there is a asynchronous function call, I have to make a closure by a self-executing anonymous function, I think this is un-convenient.

So I wonder how do you solve this kind of problem?

**2 The executing time of the asynchronous operation**

It seems that the asynchronous operation will not be executed unless the loop complete, so in my example, I have to wait for `10000*10000` times of loop.

I have not find a solution for it.

**3 Multiple thread support**

Generally I will create more than one threads to download images in Java, C#, is it possible in NodeJS?

Comment: Use async library  https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Anything that requires downloading millions of images sounds slow, possibly unnecessary if an index can be built to the existing images, and perhaps like the kind of scraping that someone might notice and shut down.

Comment: So any suggestions for this kind of tool?

Answer (score 0):

To answer point 3, node.js is single-threaded. But you can use asynchronous code and callbacks to download multiple tiles simultaneously -- your loop can move on to the next time while the previous ones are still downloading, and will be interrupted to process the callback functions once each download has finished.

Comment: Other processes can be created and download commands run in those processes.  See:  [node.js Process API](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html)